# Appending a 1D list into a 2D list and modifying it later modifies previous entries too

Tags: python

I guess, list is an object, so this behavior must be due to its reference being appended, and so all the elements get updated! **How does this work exactly and what's the right way to do this?**

Code (to increment index position discovered):

```
# generating labels for debugging
#labels = [3]*3 + [1]*3  + [4]*2
labels = [3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4]
print "labels list is", labels

counter_table = []
#counter = [0]*6
counter = [0 for i in range(6)]
for i in labels:
    curr_label = i
    counter[curr_label] = counter[curr_label] + 1
    print "current counter list is", counter
    counter_table.append(counter)
print "final counter_table is", counter_table
```

Output:

```
labels list is [3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4]
current counter list is [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
current counter list is [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
current counter list is [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
current counter list is [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0]
current counter list is [0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0]
current counter list is [0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0]
current counter list is [0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0]
current counter list is [0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0]
final counter_table is [[0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0]]
```

Comment: just re-initialise `counter` in the loop. Unless you want to stack the changes and get every "frame" in which case, a copy has to be created.

Comment: that's exactly what is happening, you are appending the same list reference every time, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list for possible solutions to this problem

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: @jarandaf That's elaborated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're reusing the reference of `counter`, which is probably what you want to keep memory of what's happening.

So just store a copy of your list

```
counter = [0]*6
for curr_label in labels:
    counter[curr_label] += 1
    print "current counter list is", counter
    counter_table.append(counter[:]) # create a copy
```

Aside: I saw that you were reluctant to use `counter = [0]*6`: it's perfectly all right to use `*` on list of immutable objects (no risk of using the same reference in that case)

Comment: Thanks! This is it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a copy of the list:

```
counter_table.append(list(counter))
```

otherwise a modification to `counter` will alter all occurrences in counter_table.